# Ract useEffect Hook does not run during router init

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using code from one of youtube tutorial, this is my app.js:

```
export default function App() {
 
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
  token: '',
  user: ''
})

useEffect(() => {

  (async () => {
    
    let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token")
  
    if(token === null){
      localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "")
      token = "";
    }

    const tokenResponse = await Axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/authentication",
       null,
      {headers: {"x-auth-token": token}}
    )

    if(tokenResponse.data){

      try{
        
        const userResponse = await Axios.get(
          "http://localhost:5000/user",
          {headers: {"x-auth-token":token}}
        ) 

        setUserData({
          token,
          user: userResponse.data
        })

      } catch(error)
      {
        console.log(error.message)
      }
    }
  })();
 
}, [])
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{userData, setUserData}}>
        <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute component={PanelComponent} path="/panel"  />
        </Switch>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </Router>

  );
}
```

After rendering pages, for the first time it will do not run my useEffect, and userData vars will be empty, how can I run authentication from use effect in synchronious way to get my user data in User Context Provider? I used useLayoutEffect, but result is the same.

It renders my router components and with private component it always shows that i am not authenticated for a while until it run use effect hook one more time, the same situation with other routes.

How can i solve this?

Comment: did you console.log in the useEffect to make sure it did not run?

Comment: you are running the code when App is loaded not when the history changes

Answer (score 0):

You need a loading variable.

```
export default function App() {
 
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
  token: '',
  user: ''
})
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); 
// serves a variable to know whether the data has beenreceived.

useEffect(() => {

  (async () => {
    
    let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token")
  
    if(token === null){
      localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "")
      token = "";
    }

    const tokenResponse = await Axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/authentication",
       null,
      {headers: {"x-auth-token": token}}
    )

    if(tokenResponse.data){

      try{
        
        const userResponse = await Axios.get(
          "http://localhost:5000/user",
          {headers: {"x-auth-token":token}}
        ) 

        setUserData({
          token,
          user: userResponse.data
        })
        setIsLoading(false) // We have the data so we set loading to false

      } catch(error)
      {
        console.log(error.message)
      }
    }
  })();
 
}, [])
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{userData, setUserData}}>
        <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute component={PanelComponent} path="/panel"  />
        </Switch>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </Router>

  );
}
```